# Get div outside parent div without position absolute

Tags: html, css, sass

I've got a little css problem.
I got a div with a max-width. In this div there is a img that needs to be positioned outside his div (to the bottom). Unfortunately I can't use position absolute because of the max-width. When I would use position absolute, at some point the width of the screen reaches the max-width and the img with position absolute will go outside the div on the right side.

I know this must sound a little messy, so I've made a `Jsfiddle:`
https://jsfiddle.net/te93s8h1/

This JS Fiddle shows a example of the issue I got. I need the green block outside the div (at the bottom) but the green block can not go outside the div on the right side. How can I achieve this?

I prefer css only.

Comment: Can you make a drawing of how you want the elements to be positioned to make the question a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind my question, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. You should add a `position: relative;` statement to the style block of your `.grid` class as demonstrated in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te93s8h1/1/).

Comment: Thx, this example helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply try this without using position absolute.

```css
.container {
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 98%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;  /* Added Position */
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}

.block_outside_div {
  position: inherit; /* Added Position */
  background-color: #0f0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 45%;  /* 45% Percentage value for move from left */
  top: 120px; /* 120px value for move from top */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block_outside_div">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```